# Is every finite subgroup the integer points of a linear algebraic group?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, lie-groups, algebraic-groups

Let $ K $ be a compact Lie group. For every finite subgroup $ \Gamma $ of $ K $ does there exist a linear algebraic group $ G $ such that the integer points are
$$
G_\mathbb{Z} \cong \Gamma 
$$
and the real points are
$$
G_\mathbb{R} \cong K 
$$

I'm interested in this because sometimes the integer points are cool like
$$
SO_3(\mathbb{Z}) \cong S_4 
$$

Comment: I mean, presumably you are aware that this puts pretty strong restrictions on $G$, what you are asking. Namely, you are asking that $G$ has both a $\mathbb{Z}$-model and is anisotropic over $\mathbb{R}$. I think this allows $G$ to essentially only be of type $B_n$ and $D_n$. In any case, I suggest you take a look at this: https://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/papers/redgpZsmf.pdf (e.g. the discussion on pg. 29). In theory this reference allows you to enumerate all such cases (at least for absolutely simple groups) and so you can just maybe check by hand. I am not sure though.